# Exporting the Transition Matrix from a markovchain object

Tags: r, list, export, markov-chains

I had a sequence of states organized as a data frame that looks like this:

```
Year1 Year2 Year3 ...
1       2     5   ...
3       9     4   ...
```

I used markovchain's `markovchainListfit` function because I'd like to construct the transition matrix for this sequence of events, so I ran:

```
myModel <- markovchainListFit(data = myData)
```

where *myData* is the data shown above.

The code seems to work, but I get back a markovchain object and I'm having trouble exporting only the transition matrix to a data frame or a matrix so I can analyze it. I know this is super simple but for some reason I'm not seeing it.

I have tried the following:

1. Exporting the whole list to a txt file  which didn't work:

   ```
   capture.output(summary(myModel), file = "myModel.txt")
   ```
2. Accessing the elements of the list like this but I got an empty list:

   ```
   tranMatrix <- myModel$estimate@markovchains
   ```
3. I also tried coercing into a different object that I know how to work with, like a data frame using:

   ```
   as(myModel, from = "markovchain", to = "data.frame")
   ```

   But I got an error

   > (Error in as(myModel, from = "markovchain", to = "data.frame"): unused arguments (from = "markovchain", to = "data.frame")

Thanks!

Comment: [Docs](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/markovchain/versions/0.6.9.12/topics/markovchainListFit) indicate the method returns a list of two slots: estimate and name. Please `print(myModel)`and/or run `str(myModel)`.

Comment: Thansk @Parfait. I tried that but when you mentioned it again I finally figured it out: tranMatrix <- myModel$estimate@markovchains[[1]]@transitionMatrix. THANK YOU!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To extract the transition matrix, I used:

```
myModel$estimate@markovchains[[1]]@transitionMatrix
```